# git commands hang when using credential helper + ssh

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, server

I use git on a remote ubuntu 14.04 system, accessed by ssh. I set up `git-credential-gnome-keyring` and was finding that it raised this error whenever accessing the remote:

`** (process:12984): CRITICAL **: Error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon`

I found a partial fix to this error [here](http://marklodato.github.io/2013/10/25/github-two-factor-and-gnome-keyring.html). The author suggests adding the following to `.bashrc`

```
if [[ -z $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS ]]; then
    if [[ -f ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0 ]]; then
        source ~/.dbus/session-bus/$(dbus-uuidgen --get)-0
        export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    fi
fi
```

If I make this change **after** manually entering my username/password once, then subsequent git commands will execute without asking for my credentials again. If I leave the session and return, or if I make the change before entering my credentials, all commands which access the remote will hang indefinitely.

Any ideas what is causing the hang?